# How to make all div boxes same height

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to make all the DIV boxes that are in LightPink and LightBlue to be the same height.

Currently the boxes have different height, also to keep a note that LightBlue boxes are scrollable vertically:

```css
.sample_3 {
  margin: 5px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sample_3 .column > div {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}

.sample_3 .box__second {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 300px;
}

.sample_3 .box__first > .column > div {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.sample_3 .box__second > .column > div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="sample_3">
      <div class="box__first">
        <div class="column">
          <div>Box 1 231232 sds sad s</div>
          <div>Box 2</div>
          <div>Box 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box__second">
        <div class="column second">
          <div>Random Text</div>
          <div>Random Text MORE MORE MORE</div>
          <div>Random Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
          <div>Random Text</div>
          <div>Random Text</div>
          <div>Random Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
          <div>Random Text</div>
          <div>Text</div>
          <div>Random Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
          <div>Random Text</div>
          <div>Random Text</div>
          <div>Random Text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have done this via Flex here but this is using different HTML structure which is not what ideal for me, but this could give a good idea what i'm trying to achieve with `sample_3`

```css
.sample_4 .wrap {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px;
}

.sample_4 .column {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}

.sample_4 .column div {
  padding: 5px;
}

.sample_4 .row > .column:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: #ffbb00;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="sample_4">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <div>Box 1 MORE MORE</div>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div>Random Text</div>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div>Random Text</div>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div>Random Text</div>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div>Random</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <div>Box 2</div>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div>Random Text Text MORE MORE MORE</div>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div>Random Text</div>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div>Random Text</div>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div>Random Text</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So end goal is to have `sample_3` all boxes to be same height and they can change the height dynamically depending on the content of other box in same row.

Comment: Why are you using the obsolete flex model `display: -webkit-box;` instead of the current `display: flex`? The two are very different: https://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/

Comment: i don't this has been added by Live Sass Compiler

Comment: I think you will need Css-grid and subgrid for this. Or perhaps css tables

Comment: i might have to explore the grid option i guess, hm i have tried with tables but running with similar issues so just exploring alternatives

Comment: try setting a max-width and overflow: hidden with text-overflow: elipsis

Comment: @Stanley would you able to post example?

Comment: @Marius give me a few minutes and i will post a solution

Comment: if i'm not mistaken text-overflow: elipsis won't work because it will just replace the text with ... i need the text to visible

Comment: @Marius is this what you want or do you want the boxes to scale with the largest div? https://i.gyazo.com/c576a9a648bbcdf13d9fb282f841fcd9.png

Comment: nevermind. took a look at your second example. Its not possible to achieve your last result without using javascript or changing the HTML structure. This is because you want the divs to be relative to each other without having relations at all

Answer (score 0):

Should try this way

```
             <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

             <style type="text/css">
               .table-responsive{
               max-width: 200px;
             }
             </style>
             <table class="table table-hover">

             <tbody>
              <tr>
                   <th scope="row">Box 1</th>
                   <td class="table-responsive">Random Text </td>
                   <td>Random Text</td>
                   <td>Random Text</td>
  
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <th scope="row">Box 2</th>
              <td class="table-responsive">RAndom Text RAndom Text RAndom Text RAndom TextRAndom TextRAndom text RAndom Textv RAndom Text RAndom Text RAndom Text RAndom Textvv RAndom Text</td>
               <td >RAndom Text</td>
               <td>RAndom Text</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <th scope="row">Box 3</th>
              <td  >Random Text</td>
              <td class="table-responsive">Random Text Random TextRandom Textvv Random Textvv Random Text vvRandom TextRandom TextRandom TextRandom Text</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

This might be helpful

Comment: yep i had something similar but with this approach is was struggling to freeze the 1st column

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest solution i could figure out, key point on this one is to use sticky because with fixed boxed are not even.

The problem with sticky is that when scrolling in mobile view only sticky element moves slightly: video example > https://streamable.com/jhz2vr

```css
.sample__two {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}

.sample__two th {
  min-width: 120px;
}

.sample__two th,
.sample__two td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sample__two .freeze {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 0px solid red;
}

.sample__two .hide {
  border: unset;
}

.sample__two thead {
  background-color: #93eccf;
}

.sample__two tbody {
  background-color: #aedb31;
}

.sample__two .test {
  background-color: #0026ff !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="sample__two">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="freeze">Empty</th>
            <th class="">Empty</th>
            <th>Ratings</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
            <th>Header 5</th>
            <th>Header 6</th>
            <th>Header 7</th>
            <th>Header 8</th>
            <th>Header 9</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="freeze">Price 1</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 1 TEST</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="freeze">Price 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I would not mind if someone has better way

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sample_3 {
  margin: 5px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.sample_3 .column {
display: flex;
height: 200px;
}
.sample_3 .box__first .column {
flex-direction: column;
}
.sample_3 .box__first .column div {
height: 200px;
}
.sample_3 .column > div {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}

.sample_3 .box__second {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 300px;
}

.sample_3 .box__first > .column > div {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.sample_3 .box__second > .column > div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="sample_3">
      <div class="box__first">
        <div class="column">
          <div>Box 1 231232 sds sad s</div>
          <div>Box 2</div>
          <div>Box 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box__second">
        <div class="column second">
          <div>Random Text</div>
          <div>Random Text MORE MORE MORE</div>
          <div>Random Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
          <div>Random Text</div>
          <div>Random Text</div>
          <div>Random Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
          <div>Random Text</div>
          <div>Text</div>
          <div>Random Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
          <div>Random Text</div>
          <div>Random Text</div>
          <div>Random Text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the blue text height i'm missing other blue in other rows

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sample__two {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}

.sample__two th {
  min-width: 120px;
}

.sample__two th,
.sample__two td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sample__two .freeze {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 0px solid red;
}

.sample__two .hide {
  border: unset;
}

.sample__two thead {
  background-color: #93eccf;
}

.sample__two tbody {
  background-color: #aedb31;
}

.sample__two .test {
  background-color: #0026ff !important;
}
.sample__two td{
height: 100px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="sample__two">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="freeze">Empty</th>
            <th class="">Empty</th>
            <th>Ratings</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
            <th>Header 5</th>
            <th>Header 6</th>
            <th>Header 7</th>
            <th>Header 8</th>
            <th>Header 9</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="freeze">Price 1</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 1 TEST</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="freeze">Price 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is the diff between this one and what i have posted myself as potential answer?

Comment: I have given td tag just a particular height.